# elixir project not compile exited in: PluralsightTweet.Application.start(:normal, [])

Tags: elixir-mix, elixir

i'm new to elixir

target - read simplet text file

started with 
mix new pluralsight_tweet --sup 
pilot project deployed success

file structure 
[image]

code in file_reader.ex

```
defmodule PluralsightTweet.FileReader do
    def get_strings_to_tweet(path) do
        File.read!(path)
     end
end
```

try to compile using

```
iex -S mix
```

give errors [image]

whats the issue and how can i fix this case

application.ex

```
defmodule PluralsightTweet.Application do
  # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    # Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
    children = [
      # Starts a worker by calling: PluralsightTweet.Worker.start_link(arg1, arg2, arg3)
      # worker(PluralsightTweet.Worker, [arg1, arg2, arg3]),
    ]

    # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: PluralsightTweet.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `application.ex`?

Comment: updated can you check

Comment: Umm, why is `lib` directory inside `test`? Did you accidentally move it? Moving it back to the root directory should fix everything.

Comment: Oopz it's work 
my bad